How long are standard sticks of butter in the USA?
There are two standard lengths of butter (meaning the sticks that say they are about 0.5 cups each). According to a websearch of mine, the shorter one is said to be popular on the west coast of the USA, and the longer one is said to be popular on the East coast (at least with certain brands).
How long, precisely, are these sticks of butter?

This is slightly harder to answer than I'd think.
The approximate answer is:

Elgin (East Coast): 121 millimetres (4.8 in) long
Western: 80 millimetres (3.1 in) long

https://www.midwestfarmreport.com/2016/07/20/the-shape-of-your-butter/
However, you'll find slightly different numbers from other sources, for example:

“East Coast butter sticks are 4.8 inches long and 1.3 inches wide. They are typically sold stacked two-by-two in elongated cube-shaped boxes...West Coast butter sticks are 3.125 inches long and 1.5 inches wide and are typically sold stacked two-by-two in a rectangle carton.”

What’s the Difference Between East Coast Butter and West Coast Butter?
Curiously, most sources I'm finding are reporting the size in only two dimensions (length and width), but I, for one, have never seen a two dimensional stick of butter.  Mine always comes in 3D; rectangular cuboids, not rectangles.
Neither of those dimensions quoted above would produce a rectangle of equal area, which means that either the third dimension must be different (the ends of the butter sticks are rectangles, not squares), or that Elgin and Western butter sticks don't actually have the same volume.  I suspect that both of those may be true.
Users participating in this Reddit discussion have provided their own measurements, which, as you can see, have some variance:

West Coast here. We get the stubby variety. I have a Darigold brand sitting in the fridge. Looks like it's 3 & 3/16" x 1.5 " x 1.5" or about 8.1 cm x 3.8 cm x 3.8 cm


In the East and Midwest (from my experience) they are:
Each stick is 8 tablespoons, 4 oz, or 113 grams. The dimensions are 12x3x3 cm


Westside. 4mm x 3.6mm x 8mm Edit: centimeters of course.


[Elgin] 11.684 centimeters in length, 3.175 centimeters wide, and 2.794 centimeters in height.


The two-dimensional butter can be found in the "diet" section.

Both the east and the west coast varieties are 4 oz=113 g?

The dimensions you describe as "East Coast" are what gets sold in Toronto, Canada, too. It honestly never occurred to me that it might be different anywhere else in North America.

One reason the person you quoted might have had ~117 cubic centimeters for the western ones, and someone reported 108 for the Eastern ones could be because they actually measured the western ones themselves, and they went by the product description for the eastern ones. When I look at a stick of butter (the short kind), it measures amounts starting at a point after the butter begins (and the product information ignores the beginning of the butter as if it's not there; I think the same is true of the long butter).

Anyway, I'm really glad you quoted someone who seems to have measured a stick of butter themselves (that's what I was hoping for).
